# MediaPlayer play through earpiece

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

OK after trying countless variations from SO, I still cant make it work. Can you tell me what is wrong with my setup? I'm trying to make the mediaplayer play through the earpiece.

I've set the permission in the manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

and this is the method that is being called before the start() for the media file:

```
private void setMediaResources() {
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
            Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

    mDialTone = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.dial_tone_0_5);
    mDialTone.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

    mDialTone2 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.dial_tone_0_5);
    mDialTone2.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

    mVoice = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.papa_noel_english);
    mVoice.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

}
```

And the log:

```
08-07 10:36:45.814: W/MediaPlayer(14667): info/warning (973, 0)
08-07 10:36:45.814: E/MediaPlayer(14667): setAudioStream called in state 8
08-07 10:36:45.814: E/MediaPlayer(14667): error (-38, 0)
08-07 10:36:45.824: W/MediaPlayer(14667): info/warning (973, 0)
08-07 10:36:45.824: E/MediaPlayer(14667): setAudioStream called in state 8
08-07 10:36:45.824: E/MediaPlayer(14667): error (-38, 0)
08-07 10:36:45.859: W/MediaPlayer(14667): info/warning (973, 0)
08-07 10:36:45.859: E/MediaPlayer(14667): setAudioStream called in state 8
08-07 10:36:45.859: E/MediaPlayer(14667): error (-38, 0)
08-07 10:36:45.859: E/MediaPlayer(14667): start called in state 0
08-07 10:36:45.859: E/MediaPlayer(14667): error (-38, 0)
08-07 10:36:45.869: I/Choreographer(14667): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-07 10:36:45.974: I/MediaPlayer(14667): Info (973,0)
08-07 10:36:45.974: I/MediaPlayer(14667): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
08-07 10:36:45.974: E/MediaPlayer(14667): Error (-38,0)
08-07 10:36:45.974: E/MediaPlayer(14667): start called in state 0
08-07 10:36:45.974: E/MediaPlayer(14667): error (-38, 0)
08-07 10:36:45.974: I/MediaPlayer(14667): Info (973,0)
08-07 10:36:45.974: I/MediaPlayer(14667): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
08-07 10:36:45.974: E/MediaPlayer(14667): Error (-38,0)
08-07 10:36:45.974: E/MediaPlayer(14667): start called in state 0
08-07 10:36:45.974: E/MediaPlayer(14667): error (-38, 0)
08-07 10:36:45.974: I/MediaPlayer(14667): Info (973,0)
08-07 10:36:45.979: I/MediaPlayer(14667): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
08-07 10:36:45.979: E/MediaPlayer(14667): Error (-38,0)
08-07 10:36:46.289: E/MediaPlayer(14667): Error (-38,0)
08-07 10:36:46.289: E/MediaPlayer(14667): start called in state 0
08-07 10:36:46.289: E/MediaPlayer(14667): error (-38, 0)
08-07 10:36:46.289: E/MediaPlayer(14667): Error (-38,0)
08-07 10:36:46.289: E/MediaPlayer(14667): start called in state 0
08-07 10:36:46.289: E/MediaPlayer(14667): error (-38, 0)
08-07 10:36:46.289: E/MediaPlayer(14667): Error (-38,0)
08-07 10:36:46.344: E/MediaPlayer(14667): Error (-38,0)
08-07 10:36:46.344: E/MediaPlayer(14667): start called in state 0
08-07 10:36:46.344: E/MediaPlayer(14667): error (-38, 0)
08-07 10:36:46.344: E/MediaPlayer(14667): Error (-38,0)
08-07 10:36:46.344: E/MediaPlayer(14667): Error (-38,0)
08-07 10:36:59.509: E/MediaPlayer(14667): stop called in state 0
08-07 10:36:59.509: E/MediaPlayer(14667): error (-38, 0)
08-07 10:36:59.509: E/MediaPlayer(14667): stop called in state 0
08-07 10:36:59.509: E/MediaPlayer(14667): error (-38, 0)
08-07 10:36:59.509: E/MediaPlayer(14667): stop called in state 0
08-07 10:36:59.509: E/MediaPlayer(14667): error (-38, 0)
```